# Mathematical expression of cumulative sum reset function

Tags: functions

Could anybody please help me to formulate an expression for the function that sums up observations along a vector, but wherever the sum becomes negative it reset the the sum to 0 and starts suming up again from that point. Assuming that Y is the function, here how it works:
[cumulative sum-reset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CLMV.png)

I guess in terms of logical operators it should look smth like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
Y_0 &= 0 \\
Y_t &= \max(X_t+Y_{t-1},0) &&\text{for $t>0$}
\end{align}

Alternative notation:
$$Y_t =
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if $t=0$} \\
\max(X_t+Y_{t-1},0) &\text{if $t>0$}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: This simplification is much elegant,  thank you @RobPratt. What I would also liked to clarify how to correctly formulate it in math syntax - should it be preceded by curly paranthesis ?

Comment: $\max()$ and $\max\{\}$ are both common syntax.

Comment: I meant the left paranthesis that embeds two equations.

Comment: ok, now I see that it does not need any paranthesis since Yo is not Yt. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, and I added an alternative to my answer just now.